# Duplicating element in 2D Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a loop which runs for the length of a 2D-Array. I need a way to duplicate one of the sub-arrays (the one loop is on) and add it to the end of the main array (making the loop go through that element as well.) Everything works properly until I try to add the new array. Abstract code is below.

```
var agent = new Array()
    agent[0] = ["Black",    0,  5,  7]
    agent[1] = ["Yellow",   1,  3,  2]
    agent[2] = ["Orange",   5,  9,  2]
    agent[3] = ["Pink",     8,  1,  5]
    agent[4] = ["Blue",     9,  5,  8]  

for(i=0;i<=agent.length;i++){
   //Test something
   if(something == true) {    
       agent.push = agent[i]
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `agent.push = agent[i]` ??? Is there some reason you thought this would work? Also, if your condition is based on that array, then you'll have an infinite loop because it'll eventually hit the one you add causing another add, and another, and so on. You need to iterate in reverse, or cache the original length.

Answer (score 1):

```
agent.push = agent[i]
```

should be

```
agent.push(agent[i]);
```

***Edit:*** if you want to copy the array, then use:

```
agent.push(agent[i].slice(0));
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my part when I simplified the code. 

The issue I have is if I edit an element in either the original agent or the new agent it edits that element in both. I want to create a copy of agent[i] but have them be separate after that.